# Redis latency history for set and get events

Tags: performance, redis, monitoring

What kind of events are supported by redis latency monitoring besides general ones like 'command', 'fast-command' and 'fork'? Only these events are mentioned in [official redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/latency-monitor)

Is it possible to monitor latency of reads or writes only?
If i run `LATENCY HISTORY command` it will give me latency spikes for 'set' events also.